# What does mean $$ or $! in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

It's kind of easy question but I didn't find any information. What does mean `$!` or `$$` in bash?

For example: `ps -p $!`  or `pstree $$`?

Comment: `man bash`, press `/` and start search.

Comment: Did you tried that? there's no info about my question

Comment: `man bash` `/special parameters` `$      Expands  to  the process ID of the shell.  In a () subshell, it expands to the process ID of the current
              shell, not the subshell.
       !      Expands to the process ID of the most recently executed background (asynchronous) command.`

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Actually, these variables were inherited by bash from the Bourne shell.

`$$` means current PID.

`$!` is the PID of the last program your shell ran in the background (e.g. `myprog &`)

Here is a list of shell variables:

- http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/scrpt/scrpt2.2.2.html

Comment: Yes, I see.. so it equals to PID of bash terminal?

Comment: If you're at the terminal prompt, yes. If you're running a shell script, then you can use `$PPID` to get the PID of your terminal shell.  Here's another link: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html

Comment: In a subshell, "$$" is not its PID even if that is current, too.

Answer (score 10):

[`$!`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#PIDVARREF) is the process ID of the last job run in the background.

[`$$`](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#PROCESSIDREF) is the process ID of the script itself.

(Both of the above are links to the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) on TDLP.)

See also the [gnu.org documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters).