# Does $! mean something in shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Does **$!** exists in bash/shell script, if yes, please inform for what it is used for. And why it gives blank when `echo $!` is run on the command line?

Comment: Also see [What does mean $$ or $! in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13671750/what-does-mean-or-in-bash/)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In addition to other answer, this echo

```
echo $!
```

Will print blank if you haven't yet run any **process in background** in current shell. If you now run:

```
date &
echo $!
```

Then it will print something like (i.e. process id of last executed background process):

```
47833
```

Answer (score 8):

`$!` is the PID of the last program your shell ran in the background

Comment: Any idea, how does it gets the PID of the last background process which has been killed or completed?

Comment: @pRAShANT There's no easy way. You could just keep a record of all the processes you ran using an array type of your choice then use a SIGCHLD trap handler to be triggered everytime a process is terminated/killed then check which process is no longer there. The method is just not accurate especially if two processes are both terminated at the same time. Checking if processes still exists by `/proc`, `kill -s 0`, etc. is also slow. And I'm not sure if process management through job control is always doable or efficient that it doesn't miss anything.

Answer (score 0):

$! - shows last process ID which has started in background.